# Как добавить диалоговое окно подтверждения закрытия процесса в диспетчере задач?

Tags: c#, task, manager

[image: черная половина]Нужно чтоб при  убийстве процесса  - выводилось диаг. окно подтверждения - Вы действительно хотите завершить процесс = да  нет = .  Вот код кнопки

```
private void KillProcess(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    proces[lstProcess.SelectedIndex].Kill(); // Получаем инд. позиции , останавливаем проц.
    MessageBox.Show("Процесс завершен!", "TsManager"); // Выводим сообщение о звершении.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выводите `MessageBox` с двумя кнопками (Да/Нет), и получаете результат в переменную `result`, дальше просто проверяете результат

```
private void KillProcess(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Завершить процесс?", "Подтвердите действие", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        proces[lstProcess.SelectedIndex].Kill(); // Получаем инд. позиции , останавливаем проц.
        MessageBox.Show("Процесс завершен!", "TsManager"); // Выводим сообщение о звершении.
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        // какое-то действие при нажатии на НЕТ
    }  
}
```

[MessageBox на MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Наверняка можно в качестве примера дать ссылку: [How do I create a message box with “Yes”, “No” choices and a DialogResult?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3036829/5275890) там много подходов к решению данного вопроса :)

Comment: @DenisBubnov можно, да и в принципе на майкрософте все написано)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все работает! Но тут проблема , при выводе  диаг. окна -  просто половина окна окрашена в черный цвет , видны только кнопки, а как сделать чтоб все диаг. окно было как обычное, белым цветом? Я прикреплю к вопросу картинку.

Comment: @ceh задайте новый вопрос, к текущему это отношения не имеет)

Comment: Понял , спасибо.
Не подскажите, лимиты на вопросы есть?

Comment: @ceh не встречал)